# How to arrange data in sql server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I tried many query to achieve the expected result , I couldn't find any solution.

Actual:-

```
ID | EmpDailyFee | EmpMonthlyFee | CompDailyFee | CompMnthlyFee

1        NULL         12            NULL               NULL

1         50         NULL           NULL               NULL

1         60         NULL           NULL               NULL

2        50           NULL           NULL               NULL

3        NULL          30            NULL               NULL
```

Expected :-

```
ID | EmpDailyFee | EmpMonthlyFee | CompDailyFee | CompMnthlyFee

1        50            12            NULL               NULL

1        60            12            NULL               NULL

2        50           NULL           NULL               NULL

3        NULL          30            NULL               NULL
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in your query? It would be helpful if you included the query you are executing and the table schemas you are querying against.

Comment: It would also be nice to know where your results are coming from? What tables are you using and what query are you trying to use?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a table smell to me since the rows are sharing the same ID value but with different EmpDailyFee/EmpMonthlyFee values. But in this particular case you can get your expected output like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.EmpDailyFee, t2.EmpMonthlyFee
FROM @Test t1
INNER JOIN @Test t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.EmpDailyFee IS NOT NULL AND t2.EmpMonthlyFee IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.ID, t1.EmpDailyFee, t1.EmpMonthlyFee
FROM @Test t1
WHERE (t1.EmpDailyFee IS NOT NULL OR t1.EmpMonthlyFee IS NOT NULL) AND t1.ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT t3.ID
    FROM @Test t3
        INNER JOIN @Test t2 ON t3.ID = t2.ID
    WHERE t3.EmpDailyFee IS NOT NULL AND t2.EmpMonthlyFee IS NOT NULL
)
```

This has been tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec9bc/1)

Note: The reason why I did not include `CompDailyFee` and `CompMnthlyFee` is because the values of both the actual and expected results were NULL. I am trying to write a "simple-as-possible" query based on what OP has provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to insert or update data this could be the solution, customizing it on your needings

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee WHERE ID = 1)
    UPDATE Employee SET EmpMonthlyFee= @Value WHERE ID = 1
ELSE
    INSERT Employee(ID,EmpDailyFee,EmpMonthlyFee,CompDailyFee,CompMnthlyFee)
    VALUES(1,NULL,@value,NULL,NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (ID int,Empfee int,monthlyfee int,compdailyfee int,Cmpnymonthlyfee int)

insert into @t (ID,Empfee,monthlyfee,compdailyfee,Cmpnymonthlyfee)
values (1,NULL,12,NULL,NULL),
(1,50,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(1,60,NULL,NULL,NULL)
;with cte as (
select t.ID,t.Empfee,
tt.monthlyfee,
t.compdailyfee,
t.Cmpnymonthlyfee,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY t.ID,tt.monthlyfee ORDER BY t.ID,tt.monthlyfee)RN 
    from @t t  
    CROSS  APPLY @t tt
where t.Empfee IS  NULL OR tt.monthlyfee IS NOT NULL) 

select C.ID,
C.Empfee,
C.monthlyfee,
C.compdailyfee,
C.Cmpnymonthlyfee from cte c
where c.Empfee IS NOT NULL AND c.monthlyfee IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi All Thanks for your Ans

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using `COALESCE` as well.

```
SELECT T1.ID, 
       T2.EmpDailyFee, 
       COALESCE(T1.EmpMonthlyFee , T2.EmpMonthlyFee) EmpMonthlyFee, 
       COALESCE(T1.CompDailyFee , T2.CompDailyFee) CompDailyFee , 
       COALESCE(T1.CompMnthlyFee , T2.CompMnthlyFee) CompMnthlyFee 

FROM 

(SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE EmpDailyFee IS NULL)T1
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE EmpDailyFee IS NOT NULL)T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

I have gone one step ahead and assumed that values from the first row will take priority if not null(As for the 3rd column in OP). This part can be neglected if not required.

Comment: Hi Sourav,                                                                                                                         Now I have diff type of data's coming in to the table . can u pls help in finding the solution.